# NAnt - how to get the directory path of the included script

Tags: path, include, directory, nant

I have a common NAnt script (containing some common targets and constants) that I include in many other NAnt scripts like this:

```
<include buildfile="<path>\common.build" verbose="true" />
```

Calling scripts are in various folders.

In this included script I need to read a file from the same directory, where included script resides.
"Current directory" is set to the directory of the calling script, not included one.
How can I get the directory path of the included script?

If I use the following construct (inside included script):

```
${ path::get-directory-name(project::get-buildfile-path()) }
```

then I get the folder path of the calling script, rather than of the included script.

Is there any way to get the path of the included script inside it?

Regards,
Ivan.

Comment: What you write is in direct conflict with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506203/nant-cant-get-current-directory-from-include - what NAnt version do you use?

Comment: No, it's not. They guy there has exactly the same problem as me.
The problem is that: in the included file you can't get the directory of the included file.
I use NAnt 0.91.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion: Define the path to the called script file in a property inside the calling script like this:

```
<property name="include.buildfile.path" value="C:\foo\common.build" />
<include buildfile="${include.buildfile.path}" verbose="true" />
```

I the common script you access the desired directory path like this:

```
${path::get-directory-name(include.buildfile.path)}
```

Comment: The Chairman, hi! Yes, I ended up with something very similar - I define property with the directory path holding the included file, and then use it to include it and also use it inside it. Thanks!

Comment: @Ivan: If that's what you went with, you should also press 'Accept' (the green 'check' mark) next to this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had a look at NAnt source code, unfortunately what you want to achieve is not doable with an existing or custom function - NAnt appends the included file into it's project structure, and while `Project` has a `LocationMap` to get back the filename from which a certain node came, it's marked as `internal`, so can't even get extracted with a script. You can either go for a workaround, like assuming a constant location of your file in relation to the master script (and walk down from there) or build a custom version of NAnt with a function exposing the functionality you need. First solution is not pretty, second one is not easy.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I've chosed "not pretty" but easy solution :) See my reply to The Chairman.